# Is there an idiom for assigning a var to the result of an unsafe call and using that var later without nesting everything else inside of unsafe{}?

Tags: rust

I would like to assign `someval` to the result of an unsafe call and use `someval` later:

```
fn partially_unsafe(item: *const scary_c_struct) -> i32 {
    let someval = item.as_ref();
    match someval {
        Some(big_long_block) => {
            //lots of lines of code
            42
        }
        None => -1,
    }
}
```

This doesn't compile because `item.as_ref()` needs to be in an `unsafe` block:

```
fn partially_unsafe(item: *const scary_c_struct) -> i32 {
    unsafe {
        let someval = item.as_ref();
        match someval {
            Some(big_long_block) => {
                //lots of lines of code
                42
            }
            None => -1,
        }
    }
}
```

This seems cumbersome if there's a lot of other nested blocks in the function.

I could use this expression, but this subverts immutability:

```
// ...
let mut someval = None;
unsafe {
    someval = item.as_ref();
}
// ...
```

I could also hide the `item.as_ref()` in its own function.

None of these seem satisfactory. Is there less cumbersome way to express unsafe assignments?

Comment: I would recommend the whole `partially_unsafe` function to be marked unsafe (`unsafe fn partialy_unsafe ...`) because it has a contract that needs to be fulfilled that the Rust type system and borrow checker cannot ascertain - namely, that the `*const scary_c_struct` pointer be valid. Documenting the existence of such a contract is the reason why `unsafe fn` exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The immediate answer is: **Deferred Initialization**

```
let someval;
unsafe {
    someval = item.as_ref();
}
// use someval
```

However, is that what you really want?

The ugly truth of `unsafe` is that it is **pervasive**, and percolates far beyond the boundary of the `unsafe` block.

For example, the above allows:

```
let someval; // &T
unsafe {
    someval = &*(ptr::null() as *const T);
}
```

in which case the crash will likely occur *outside* the `unsafe` block, even though its origin is within the `unsafe` block.

Therefore, shrinking the `unsafe` block is here counter-productive; it induces a false sense of security.

Comment: Either way it will panic, right?  Is there a difference between crashing inside vs. outside the unsafe block?

Comment: @marathon this won't be a *panic*, which is a controlled situation. This is some lower level memory error like a segfault. And a crash is the **good** case. It's also likely that you expose secret information (e.g. passwords) corrupt data, allow for arbitrary code execution, etc.

Comment: On the contrary, I'd say that shrinking the `unsafe` block makes it more likely that you will realize immediately the error is somewhere else. Increasing the scope of the `unsafe` block just increases the amount of code you have to search for the "actual unsafety" (e.g. initializing a pointer to null) and does nothing to reduce the amount of code you have to search for the logical error that caused the error.

Answer (score 3):

There's no need for deferred evaluation here; blocks and unsafe blocks are expressions too:

```
fn partially_unsafe(item: *const scary_c_struct) -> i32 {
    let someval = unsafe { item.as_ref() };
    match someval {
        Some(big_long_block) => {
            //lots of lines of code
            42
        }
        None => -1,
    }
}
```

> but this subverts immutability

You can always give up mutability by rebinding the variable:

```
let mut a = 0;
a += 1;
let a = a;
```

> I could also hide the `item.as_ref()` in its own function.

That would be silly as the function would be identical to `as_ref` and would still need to be marked as `unsafe`, so you would gain nothing. It would make *far* more sense to do the opposite — move the safe (or at least *safer*) code out of this function:

```
fn partially_unsafe(item: *const scary_c_struct) -> i32 {
    unsafe {
        item.as_ref().map_or(-1, |item| item.extracted_method())
    }
}
```

---

[Matthieu M.'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45468865/155423) is spot-on about the scope of unsafe serving a purpose for the human in addition to requirements of the compiler. It's useful to use the scope of the block to highlight where the unsafety can reach.